# Segfault conundrum

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

So i am curious as to why the following segment of code keeps segfaulting. It looks correct to me.

```
int * addCoins(char *val){
    const char *deli = ",";
    char *ptr =NULL;

    char *denomination = strtok_r(val, deli, &ptr);
    char *count = strtok_r(NULL, deli, &ptr);
    int deno = atoi(denomination);
    int cnt = atoi(count);
    int *k;
    k = malloc(sizeof(*k)*2);
    k[0] = deno;
    k[1] =cnt;

    return k;
}
```

the call to the function addCoins in main. I do not think the fault lies in here but i honestly am at a bit of loss with this problem.

```
char* fileNameCoin = argv[2];
FILE *fileCoin;
fileCoin = fopen(fileNameCoin, "r+");
char bufCoin[256];
int i = 0;
//vmNode->next = NULL;
int *j;
while (fgets(bufCoin, sizeof bufCoin, fileCoin) != NULL) {
    j = addCoins(bufCoin);
    int deno = j[0];
    switch(deno){
    case 5:
        Coins[i].denom = j[0];
        Coins[i].count = j[1];
        break;
    case 10:
        Coins[i].denom = j[0];
        Coins[i].count = j[1];
        break;
    case 20:
        Coins[i].denom = j[0];
        Coins[i].count = j[1];
        break;
    case 50:
        Coins[i].denom = j[0];
        Coins[i].count = j[1];
        break;
    case 100:
        Coins[i].denom = j[0];
        Coins[i].count = j[1];
        break;
    case 200:
        Coins[i].denom = j[0];
        Coins[i].count = j[1];
        break;
    case 500:
        Coins[i].denom = j[0];
        Coins[i].count = j[1];
        break;
    case 1000:
        Coins[i].denom = j[0];
        Coins[i].count = j[1];
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }

    i++;
}
```

The following is how the file is defined

> 1000,3
>
> 500,4
>
> 200,20
>
> 100,30
>
> 50,5
>
> 20,3
>
> 10,40
>
> 5,20

where the first number is the denomination in cents, and the 2nd column is the number of said denomination.

These are the typedefs:

```
    /* The different denominations of coins available */
    enum denomination
    {
        FIVE_CENTS, TEN_CENTS, TWENTY_CENTS, FIFTY_CENTS, ONE_DOLLAR,
        TWO_DOLLARS, FIVE_DOLLARS, TEN_DOLLARS
    };

    /* Each coin in the coins array will have a denomination (20 cents,
     * 50 cents, etc) and a count - how many of that coin do we have on hand
     */
    struct coin
    {
        enum denomination denom;
        unsigned count;
    };
```

Comment: `const char *deli = ",";..strtok_r(val, deli, &ptr)..strtok_r(NULL, deli, &ptr)` .. `k = malloc(sizeof(*k)*2);k[0] = deno;k[1] =cnt;`

Comment: Yup i did this still segfaulting.

Comment: `val` Is it rewritable?

Comment: yes. Its faulting at the strtok_r line. As it will not run any code past this line.

Comment: see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/6WZLKX)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i made your suggested changes and it is still faulting. I have added the call to the function in the code also.

Comment: `j[1],j[2]` --> `j[0],j[1]`

Comment: yup fixed that thanks.

Comment: What is `bufCoin` and how is it being defined? Also i'd say the error is somewhere else in the code. Can you post more of the software? How do you know it's crashing there?

Comment: @RedX
 char* fileNameCoin = argv[2];
 FILE *fileCoin;
 fileCoin = fopen(fileNameCoin, "r+");
 char bufCoin[256];

Comment: What is written in the file?

Comment: 1000,3
500,4
200,20
100,30
50,5
20,3
10,40
5,20

Comment: @RedX i have added the file format, and the type defs for you all too look at.

Comment: It's not a good idea to change the relevant parts of the question after answers/comments had been given, as those changes might make those answers/comments already in place ununderstandable.

Comment: i was merely providing more information. As i am still getting this annoying segfault and i have no idea where it is coming from.

Comment: Are those empty lines between the numbers also there in the real file?

Comment: Nah just for formatting on here i found the bug. It was located further along but was only messing with the addCoins function it was weird

Comment: Fell free to delete your question if you think it won't help anybody else. Otherwise please post your comment as an answer and mark it, so this question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `strtok()`/`strtok_r()` describes a **set** of delimiters, by expecting a `0`-terminated array of `char`s, that is a C-"string".

From [`strtok()`/`strtok_r()`'s man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html):

> The delim argument specifies a set of bytes that delimit the tokens in the parsed string.

So it's usage shall be:

```
const char deli[2] = {',', '\0'};
...
char * denomination = strtok_r(val, deli, &ptr);
```

or even more straight forward:

```
const char deli[] = ",";
...
char * denomination = strtok_r(val, deli, &ptr);
```

or just drop the definition of `deli` and do:

```
char * denomination = strtok_r(val, ";", &ptr);
```

---

Also the code should check whether the calls to `strtok_t()` returned `NULL` before passing the result to `atoi()`, as the latter will fail miserably if being fed a `NULL`.

Comment: This returns the error passing argument2 strtok_r makes pointer from integer without cast.

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf: You also need to change the definition of `deli` as per my answer.

Comment: i made the suggested change and added where it is being called to give a better idea. I have no idea still.